# ANY word in predicate with two to-many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

My CoreData model have 3 entities with to-many relationships:
  **job <<-->> group <<-->> person**
So groups can do different jobs, and persons can be involved in different groups.
I want to fetch all persons that do some job.
My mind sugests me to write something like this:
  **ANY group. ANY job == 'some job'**
But I know this is wrong. :) Would next predicate be correct and do what I mean:
  **ANY group.job == 'some job'**
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a predicate to find all people that do some job.

```
NSSet* groups = someJob.groups; //this will get all group that does the job
NSMutableSet* people = [NSMutableSet set];
for(Group* aGroup in groups){
  [people unionSet:aGroup.people];  //this will add the people in this group
}
//now people set has all the people that does the job
```

Comment: Yeah, I really can deal without precicate here :) Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Although NSPredicate does support dot syntax, not with to-many relationships.  Maybe the best solution would be to do two separate fetch requests with the predicate matching @"ANY job LIKE group" and @"ANY group LIKE job" and intersect the results.